# How to concat item in list with condition

Tags: c#, linq

I'm beginner to use linq in C#.
I want to concat same items in list using linq when second data of item exist in ref list.
I try to select new list by splitting with delimter but I can't get the expected result.

You find as below my code that i used :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{   
    List<String> ref_list = new List<String>();
    List<String> new_list = new List<String>();
    String exist_pattern = "|T";
    
    public bool CheckExistData(String data)
    {
        if (ref_list.Any(item => item == data))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public void Main()
    {
        ref_list.Add("X2014");
        ref_list.Add("PN14");
        
        new_list.Add("new|P7787");
        new_list.Add("data|987AA");
        new_list.Add("pnal|PN14");
        new_list.Add("mapping|884AW");
        new_list.Add("larou|X2014");
        new_list.Add("data2|PAWLL");
        
        new_list= new_list.Select(r => string.Concat(r, "|T")).Where(s=> CheckExistData(s.Split('|')[1])).ToList();
            
    }
}
```

**Expected Result :**

```
new|P7787
data|987AA
pnal|PN14|T
mapping|884AW
larou|X2014|T
data2|PAWLL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use linq than you can write it into the Select Part

```
new_list = new_list.Select(l => CheckExistData(l.Split('|')[1]) ? l+exist_pattern : l).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for loop is more suitable than linq in your case.
linq is a **query** language, but you want to **update** the orignal list.

```cs
            for (int i = 0; i < new_list.Count; i++)
            {
                string item = new_list[i];
                string[] parts = item.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                //assert parts.Length == 2
                if (ref_list.Contains(parts[1]))
                {
                    new_list[i] = item + exist_pattern;
                }
            }
```

Here's code if you really want linq.
But I really think first approach is better, more straitforward, and maintainable.

1. The linq way recreates all items, think if you have millions of items, but only one item matches, the performance is worse.
2. If you have other logic in the check than just `Contains`, more than `true` or `false`, then it is harder to construct a linq without introducing a third (including anonymous) type or function.

```
            new_list = new_list
                .Select(x => ref_list.Contains(x.Split(new char[] { '|' })[1])
                ? x + exist_pattern
                : x)
            .ToList();
```